# Как сделать отсортированный список, чтобы повторялся только 1 параметр?

Tags: c#, linq

LINQ
У меня есть список успехов пользователей, модель:

```
{
"id",
"username",
"result"
}
```

Как с помощью LINQ лист, отсортировать список, чтобы были только лучшие результаты пользователя? Чтобы 1 пользователь был только 1 раз

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отсортировать, сгруппировать, выбрать:

```
list.OrderByDescending(r => r.result).GroupBy(r => r.username).Select(g => g.First())
```

Comment: возможно `OrderByDescending`? А то выбирает самые худшие ) Ну или в `Select` => `Last()`

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Да, согласен)

Comment: Ну и `OrderByDescending` лучше в конце поставить, чтобы сортировка была последней операцией.

Comment: А разве тогда не первый возьмётся, а лучший по имени??